# Get set not covering in Test Class - Apex

Tags: apex

Getter , setter in test class not getting covered

Here is the code ?

**Method :**

```
public static List<SelectOption> UserList
{
    get
    {            
        /*string role='';
        if(issueTeam == 'Contracts')
            role = 'Contract Owner';
        else if(issueTeam == 'Buyer')
            role = 'Buyer';
        else
            role = 'Master Data Allocator';*/

        UserTemp = [Select u.LastName, u.Id, u.FirstName,u.Name, u.Email From User u ORDER BY u.Name];

        UserList = new List<SelectOption>();
        UserList.add(new SelectOption('--Select--','--Select--'));
        for(User temp : UserTemp)
        {
            UserList.add(new SelectOption(temp.Id, temp.Name));
        }
        return UserList;
    }
    set;
}
```

In Test Class

I am calling like this :

```
List<SelectOption> temp1     = TaskReportingMasterDataIssueController.UserList;
```

Please do respond !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I read your code, I understand you should make multiple test cases and in each one of them provide the corresponding values to `issueTeam` and query records so that all of the code is executed.

In the test line you have provided you are not including any context so I assume you're missing it in your tests.